# Beginner openGL and Android confusion

Tags: android, opengl-es

I know openGL is used for games, but is it possible to use OpenGL on stuff like Android Views? For example, clicking a button will cause the button to (explode/dance/etc/etc) using OpenGL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Android, you need to implement **GLSurfaceView** and **GLSurfaceView.Renderer**.
There is official documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

and a good starter tutorial can be found here: http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/

OpenGL isn't restricted to only games. It's a tool for creating visuals and this can be anything from 3D object models to buttons that explode and dance.

Comment: You can also use the new TextureView.  It is slightly more powerful and easier to use since it acts like a normal View.  But doing OpenGL on it is also more difficult to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html